# SqlDatasource process records before display

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a database with link urls and their respective display texts. I need to check if they are broken or not before their display string is shown in the gridview.

I am using `SqlDatasource`, is there a way to process records and use custom HTML markup to show them while using the `SqlDataSource`?

I am trying to use the `OnSelected` event of `SqlDatasource` but cant get how to use it.

Comment: selected event , but i am new to ASP so did not get documentation jargon

Comment: What do you mean by "selected event"? Can you please edit your question and explain exactly what you are trying to do, what you did try and what didn't work?

Comment: I see what you mean But I am clueless on how to do it, the closest i came was to use SqlDataSource1_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e) but dont know how to get the data rows inside this method

Comment: Please edit **the question**, not add a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is make sure that the hyperlink is valid before it gets put into the datagrid.  To do this, you would need to subscribe to the RowDataBound event on your grid.  From there, you can run code to evaluate your URL.  Here is a quick example that would check to be sure that the URL field is not an empty string:

```
protected void selectedBookList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Row != null) && (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow))
    {
        string test = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "URL").ToString();

        if (test.Length == 0)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[3].Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.Cells[3].Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of testing to be sure the length is equal to zero, you could check to see if the link is dead or not.  Once you have evaluated it, you can hide the cell like I am doing here or you could modify the link, put in a generic link, etc.